# alternative to FULL_WAKE_LOCK in service

Tags: android

I need to turn screen ON, then push message arrived, so i start intentService from WakefulBroadcastReceiver, and in service create notification, then turn screen on by this code:

```
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if(!pm.isScreenOn())
    {
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE
                , "MyLock");
        wl.acquire(5000);
    }
```

this works well

However, PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated now, and i don't see way how to use LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON in service, as documentation suggests.
Any alternatives to  FULL_WAKE_LOCK ?? How to avoid using deprecated api? 
Is there are another way to light up screen on notification receive?

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Comment: @nicolas, can you provide some code, please?

Comment: those days, the best I can do is providing you a github project that does that: https://github.com/AlexKorovyansky/WearPomodoro

Comment: @nicolas It seems that you use FULL_WAKAE_LOCK after all in your WakefulBroadcastReceiver class. So this isn't really an answer to orium's question.

Answer (score 0):

For using LayoutParams-

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```